# use case when with criteria from other table without relational key

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have table A as seen below:

```
Name     Amount
Bob      245.000.000 
Jack     98.123.000 
Mike     450.000.000 
Smith    455.000.000 
John     500.000.000
```

and table B as parameter table as

```
Class                 Range_min    Range Max
<= 100 MIO            0            100000000  
> 100 - 250 MIO       100000001    250000000 
> 250 - 450 MIO       250000001    450000000
> 450 MIO             450000001
```

can somebody help me to get a result as below:

```
Class            #ofRecord
<= 100 MIO        1
> 100 - 250 MIO   1
> 450 MIO         3
```

and If i modified the parameter table (the class or range), i don't need to change the query.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I assume you're using `.` as a thousands separator in your first table and we can safely remove it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the following statement:

```
SELECT [Class], COUNT(*)
FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB
  ON TableA.Amount BETWEEN COALESCE(TableB.[Range_min], TableA.Amount) AND
     COALESCE(TableB.[Range Max], TableA.Amount)
GROUP BY [Class]
```

And you can see the working [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/98ee9/1) as well.

Few notes:
 1. You have an incorrect "requested output". "Mike" is in 250-450.
 2. You really should use some naming convention to your columns. (`Range_min`, `Range Max`)

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple join between two tables:

```
declare @A table (Name varchar(17) not null,Amount bigint not null)
declare @B table (Class varchar(31) not null,Range_min bigint not null,Range_Max bigint null)
insert into @A(Name,Amount) values
('Bob'  ,245000000),
('Jack' ,98123000 ),
('Mike' ,450000000),
('Smith',455000000),
('John' ,500000000)

insert into @B(Class,Range_min,Range_Max) values
('<= 100 MIO'     ,0        ,100000000),
('> 100 - 250 MIO',100000001,250000000),
('> 250 - 450 MIO',250000001,450000000),
('> 450 MIO'      ,450000001,null     )

select b.Class,COUNT(*)
from
    @B b
        inner join
    @A a
        on
            b.Range_min <= a.Amount and
            (
                a.Amount <= b.Range_Max or
                b.Range_Max is null
            )
group by b.Class
```

Which produces the result:

```
Class                           
------------------------------- -----------
<= 100 MIO                      1
> 100 - 250 MIO                 1
> 250 - 450 MIO                 1
> 450 MIO                       2
```

Which doesn't match your expected result but does seem correct given the sample data.